# What was the volume of the universe a short time after the big bang?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

I assume this question is somehow ill posed, but I do not know in which way.

I think it is not a difference here whether the universe expanded into space,
or space expanded itself.

Seen from the inside, expanding means changing the volume, so there is a volume, right?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)